# Android Studio doesnt render WebP format

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, drawable, webp

I am trying to use webp format pictures in my drawable folder. But unfortunately android studio cant render the file and it is not shown on the layout. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Yeah getting the same. Seems odd now that this is Googles own format and that they want wider adoption...

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported, but no official response for resolution yet. follow the updates here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=47622

Answer (score 0):

The fix already been rolled out to:

> Available in 2.2 preview 1.

Should be fixed in the next stable release whenever that is!